# is there something wrong in my server polling method?

Tags: jquery, polling

im trying to get a post from a php file when it has something from the database.

this is the js script that sends the post request (im using jquery and the smartupdater plugin)

```
function update(){

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myp").smartupdater({

url:"listen.php",

type: POST

minTimeout:2000
},function(data){

$("#myp").before(data);

};

});
return false;
};
```

and my php file:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

$date=date();

while($date=>$ddate)
{

usleap(10000);
clearstatcache();

$search=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search);

$ddate=$row['date'];

}


echo $row['message'] . "<br/>";



?>
```

i dont know whats wrong, am i doing the whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is not `SORT BY`, it is `ORDER BY`

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

You are also missing `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get variable like `$search['date'];`

Here is how it should be:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search);
echo $row['date'];
```

Comment: yes, i forgot about that too, but it still doesnt ever give a response, i dont know if i did the while loop correctly.

Comment: @Petre: Try removing the while loop and then see because you are getting only one record anyway with `limit 1`

Comment: i removed the while loop but i still dont get a response.
in my head section i have 2 scripts, one sends the data to the server and works fine, and the one i posted here for the update, but if i dont but them inside separate script tags, the browser makes a GET request and i can see the input in the adress bar.
is this how i should do it? spearate them with script tags or is this a problem too and they should be ok in the same script tag?